# how to override logrotate for specific upstart service

Tags: linux, centos, logrotate

I have one serice `myservice` which run using `upstart`. It create logs files in `/var/log/upstrart/` directory.

My service is generating too much logs, I have to work on that, till that time, I have to rotate my logs file based on size instead of time. My default configuration for `logrotate` is.

```
/var/log/upstart/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 7
        compress
        notifempty
        nocreate
}
```

Can I override this only for `myservice` ?

Can write my won `logrotate.conf` and add in `/etc/init.d/myservice` folder and it will override the existing config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if `myservice` is run using `upstart`, it has a configuration file `/etc/init/myservice.conf` and possibly a compatibility file `/etc/init.d/myservice`, but the latter is not a directory. It is very nonstandard to have subdirectories under either `/etc/init` or `/etc/init.d`.

That said, it is a very bad idea to change files which are part of the distro, because your changes might get overridden by an upgrade. All distros have mechanisms to avoid that, but you can never be sure they will work. So don’t mess up with `/etc/logrotate.d/upstart` or wherever the stanzas you quote are from. This means you cannot have your log file under `/var/log/upstart`.

The easiest solution for you is to create a directory `/var/log/myservice/`, edit the file `/etc/init/myservice.conf` to instruct your service to log to `/var/log/myservice/myservice.log` (this is the trickiest part, read below) and then create a file `/etc/logrotate.d/myservice` with the stanzas you want.

[Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/114052/logging-a-daemons-output-with-upstart) has some hints on how to instruct your daemon to log somewhere else (you usually divert logging from upstart to syslog, then tell syslog where to log). I cannot tell you more since I know nothing about your service.